# When I click on an input from Android 4.2.2 native browser it blinks blue

Tags: android, css, browser, input

I'm making a web-app using jQuery Mobile, but I'm having some problems with the native browser on Android 4.2.2. When I tap an input element (select or text) it turns blue for as long as I am tapping the element.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following CSS:

```
input {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
```